# Parse Push in swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I was just wondering if there was any documentation on how to do push notifications in swift? All of the current documentation is written in the Objective C.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parse SDK is currently only available in Objective-C. You can use techniques detailed [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html) to use it with swift.